# Local DNS cache keeps reverting A record after clearing

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns, localhost

I wish to clear my local DNS cache so that I can access a server via a domain name which has recently had its DNS A record changed. For illustration purposes, lets assume the following:

**Domain:** mydomain.com

**Old IP address** 111.111.111.111

**New IP address** 222.222.222.222

Everything seems to be updated at my ISP's DNS and on my router's DNS cache:

```
$ dig @<ISP DNS> mydomain.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com. 7186  IN  A   222.222.222.222

$dig @<router>
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com. 7186  IN  A   222.222.222.222
```

The local cache however, is not updated:

```
$ dig mydomain.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com. 7186  IN  A   111.111.111.111
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
```

Clearing the local cache seems to work, but only temporarily:

```
$ systemd-resolve --statistics;systemd-resolve --flush-caches;systemd-resolve --statistics
Cache                      
  Current Cache Size: 1    
          Cache Hits: 12222
        Cache Misses: 6507 

<omitted>

Cache                      
  Current Cache Size: 0    
          Cache Hits: 12222
        Cache Misses: 6507 

$ dig mydomain.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com. 7186  IN  A   222.222.222.222
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
```

However, after some time, seemingly at random, I can no longer access the server via the domain name. Running `dig` again shows that the local cache has reverted back while the router and ISP's entries have remained correct:

```
$ dig mydomain.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com. 7186  IN  A   111.111.111.111
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)

$ dig @<ISP DNS> mydomain.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com. 7186  IN  A   222.222.222.222

$dig @<router>
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com. 7186  IN  A   222.222.222.222
```

I have not figured out how to reliably reproduce the problem. The first time, it reverted overnight. Today it reverted within a few seconds. In between, I have tried accessing the domain name via Firefox which has sometimes correctly loaded the site, and sometimes not (following which a check of the local DNS cache shows it has reverted).

Any suggestions would be most welcome.